# Bluetooth connection between ios and non ios device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-bluetooth

Can we connect a Bluetooth watch (not iOS OS) with any iOS mobile. if yes then how to develop the code for it in x code through objective C?

Comment: i don't think so, if it will work then who will buy 399$ iWatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can,just like normal BLT devices via protocol.Look up [Apple CoreBluetooth Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html).This will tell you how to dev,it will be a really long answer.

Comment: Yeah, you can. Just treat it like any normal bluetooth device, detect and connect.